# When said Invertible can I conclude its fails to be a subspace?

Tags: vector-spaces

Consider a system of linear equations AxT(T is Transpose)=0,where A is an invertible square matrix of order 2 and x=(x1​,x2​).Let W={x=(x1​,x2​)∣x∈R2 and AxT=0} be a subset of R2 with the usual addition and scalar multiplication as in R2.Then, W is a subspace of R2.

Is it right to say this statement is false as A is invertible and fails one of the subspace properties. Can I conclude this without checking the vector property?

Comment: No you can not because the statement is true.  The nullspace (*also called the kernel*) of a matrix *is always* a subspace regardless what $A$ is... and is one of the [four fundamental subspaces](https://brilliant.org/wiki/fundamental-subspaces/) corresponding to a linear transformation like a matrix.  With $A$ being invertible you should further be able to conclude even more about what exactly $W$ looks like.

Comment: Which of the subspace properties did you think it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose that $Ax^T=0$ and $A$ is invertible.

> Since $A$ is invertible, $A^{-1}$ exists.  Let's multiply both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$

$~$

> $A^{-1}Ax^T= A^{-1}0$

$~$

> $x^{T}=0$